# How to fix 'Make sure relevant pages are shared with integration' error when accessing Notion DB with serverless function?

Tags: serverless, netlify, notion-api, webflow

I am using a serverless function deployed on Netlify to fetch data from a Notion database with an Internal Integration Token and trying to fetch the data with:

```
const promise = fetch('<deployed website url on netlify>/.netlify/functions/notion-proxy');
promise.then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

The serverless function is reached because I get my custom error in the catch statement ("Internal server error") and an error message in the body: "Make sure the relevant pages and databases are shared with your integration" - even though I have already shared the database with the integration. I have checked that the integration has the appropriate permissions to access the database, and I have also tried sharing the database with the integration again, but the error still persists.

[Notion permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqKCO.png)

Here's the serverless function's code:

```
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";

const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
const databaseId = process.env.DATABASE_ID;

const notion = new Client({ auth: apiKey });
const username = ""; // Notion username

const handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const response = await notion.databases.query({
            database_id: databaseId,
            filter: {
                property: "ID",
                rich_text: {
                    contains: username,
                },
            },
        });

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(response),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error.body: ", error.body);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                error: "Internal server error",
                errorBody: error.body
            }),
        };
    }
};

module.exports = { handler };
```

What else can I do to solve this issue?

I've updated the code and now the serverless function is reached but I still can't fetch the data from the notion database - the error asks me to check the permissions for the integration although I already added all of the permissions (later on I want to query the fetched data on Webflow)

Comment: After playing around with the code I figured out that I wasn't being authorized for Notion with this API key: 

const apiKey = "...";
// ...
const notion = new Client({ auth: apiKey }); 

Since the  notion variable ends up being empty. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Solved the error - that was a wrong id after all.  I had to copy the URL of the database after clicking on the database and then choosing "View database" and only the copying the database id